# remote source control for personal flex projects

Tags: apache-flex, version-control

Can anyone suggest good places for source control on personal Flex projects, and what eclipse plug-ins are available for these source control services? I'd like to add some personal projects to source control when they are ready.

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 1):

I use [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com). They offer low cost private svn and git repository hosting. You could use the [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org) plugin with Eclipse and svn.